# 502 error after updates on FreeBSD 8.1

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, freebsd

I am using `NGINX+PHPFPM` on a `FreeBSD 8.1` system, everything has been going fine until today when I did a `portmanager -u`(updates). After rebooting the system, I began getting 502's when attempting to post something onto my site, only with POST did this happen. I checked my `NGINX` configuration, my `PHPFPM` configuration, everything is the same as before, the socket is running, everything seems exactly the same. I don't understand the issue. I really need to get this fixed fast so if anyone has any suggestions or ideas please recommend. I'm not an advanced `FreeBSD` user so please be patient with me.

NGINX error log reads:

```
2012/10/28 03:57:20 [error] 958#0: *160 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: **.**.**.**, server: ..., request: "POST /post.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php.sock:", host: "...", referrer: "..."
```

Comment: It might be interesting which ports you upgraded. The last nginx update has been already a mongth ago. One possibility is, that your application does not work with the latest PHP.

Comment: You are correct! I ended up reinstalling PHP and it resolved the issue. Thanks for the reply.